# mpirun is stuck when using more than 95 nodes in a cluster of 128 nodes

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpi, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

When trying to run a "hello world" with `openmpi`, for more than 95 nodes, the `mpirun` command-line is stuck (hangs) for a long time and afterwards terminates by itself.

The OpenMPI version used is v4.1.0 running on a KVM VM with Raspbian 32-bit based on Debian 11.8.

The 128 worker nodes in the Cluster are all KVM VMs of the same configuration (hardware and software).

The master node is a dedicated master and only used for controlling and monitoring. Main memory consumption on the master is not the root cause issue. I monitored the resources with `htop` while running `mpirun`.

The `mpirun` tool is not stuck when using only 95 nodes. With 96 nodes or more, the result is always the same (stuck and terminated process after many minutes).

`mpirun` does not give back an error message.

Running `mpirun` with `--verbose` did not result in some useful information.

What can I try in such a situation to find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: so it works but takes an abnormally high amount of time? that typically occurs when some interfaces have firewalls. try restricting to a single interface you know works and have no firewall on it, for example `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include eth0 --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 ...`

Comment: you can also try `mpirun --mca plm_rsh_no_tree_spawn true --mca routed_radix 128 ...`